# ClientProtocolException - Android - php

Tags: java, php, client

I'm used to figure the problems out myself but I'm really stuck this time. Would be great if someone could give me a clue.

The problem:
My android application calls a php script (say script1.php) which use "header" php function to redirect another script (say script2.php).

If I run http://xxxxxx.com/script1.php?param1=y&param2=y2&param3=y3 in the browser it works ok but if the application runs the following code it crashes.

```
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1",param1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2",param2));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param3",param3));;


    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxx.com/script1.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.v("println", "response: "+response);
    }catch(Exception e1){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection"+e1.toString());
    }
```

I've checked everything. Script1.php get the proper parameters from android app but that one throw a org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

Comment: I got the very same problem, please if you find out the solution tell me too mate.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be at Php Script. Please ensure that your script is accepting your request as post  or request method.

Comment: This is a comment at most and not a suitable answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1",param1));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2",param2));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param3",param3));;


try{
    HttpParams httpParams=new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxx.com/script1.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    Log.v("println", "response: "+response);
}catch(Exception e1){
    Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection"+e1.toString());
}
```